# R - sort function changes the matrix

Tags: r, sorting, ranking

I want to sort a column of a matrix according to the rank of the row sums of the other columns. So I use this code:

```
for(j in 1:d) {
    X[,j]=sort(X[,j],decreasing=TRUE)[rank(rowSums(X[,c(1:d)[-j]]))]
}
```

But this code changes the values of the column, which I just want to rearrange. 
When the row sums are equal, the value of the j-th column becomes equal too, despite the fact that there is every value just once in the original column. An example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNtYZ.jpg)

How can I avoid this issue?

Thanks

Comment: You probably need a comma at the end of your `rank` statement - as it stands you are just indexing in one dimension, which means R is sorting it as a vector.

Comment: That doesn't work in my example. But it should be sorted as a vector or not?

Comment: You're aware that you're reordering the columns independently at each step and then using the modified matrix to compute new ranks ? I think you might be looking for `for(j in 1:d) {  X[,j]=X[order(rowSums(X[,c(1:d)[-j]]),decreasing=TRUE),j] }` but I'm not sure what you're tryig to achieve. It'd be easier with a reproducible example and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
#sample data
x <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), nrow=3, ncol=3, byrow=T)

#if you want to sort by row-sum of 2nd & 3rd column
x[order(rowSums(x[,-1]), decreasing = T),]
#if you want to sort by row-sum of 1st & 2nd column
x[order(rowSums(x[,-3]), decreasing = T),]
```

So the final looping could be

```
x <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), nrow=3, ncol=3,byrow=T)
X <- x
for(j in 1:ncol(x)) {
  X[,j]=x[order(rowSums(x[,-j]), decreasing = T),j]
}
```